# Documenting XSD.Any ideas?

Tags: xsd

Working on a project where we use xsd to validate our xml schema.

The boss wants every field documented/To have a description and needless to say he does not want to spend any money on tools.

Before I reinvent the wheel, is there any free tool to generate and edit document from an xsd.

I did google but they all seem to be pay ones and the free one dont seem to be doing what I am after

any suggestions?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [xsd:annotation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256102.aspx) to document the schema at field level. Almost all of the major XML IDE's can display this documentation contextually (i.e. when focused on a particular element or attribute) and can also generate the documentation for your entire schema in whichever format you desire (pdf, html etc).

Answer (score 0):

Given up and just going to add annotations to schema manually.
Any trial version is not good as its a continuous upgrading